# view returns null after compact in controller

Tags: laravel

in my laravel project i have a index function like this

```
 public function index(User $user)
{

    return view('auth.verification',compact('user'));
}
```

when I dd($user) I have data but when I dd($user) in my view it will return an empty collection
but when I define a test variable and put some data in it and compact it with my view it view return data correctly
any idea why this happening?
here is my code

```
 @dd($user)
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">فعالسازی</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('verification') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">کد فعال سازی را وارد کنید</h2>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{}}">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="کد فعالسازی" name="active_code" required autofocus>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit" name="btn">فعال کن</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get the same thing when you do `return view('auth.verification',['user'=>$user]);`?

Comment: Do you have a view composer or something that sets `$user` for certain/all views? Does it show when you explicitly get a certain user `$user=User::find(1);`?

Comment: your table DB named user or users ?

Comment: check your Route model binding or update your question with the route. That might be the issue

Comment: @ChristopheHubert yes it returns an empty collection

Comment: @kerbholz in my controller when I dd($user) it return my data completely but after I compact i get an empty collection in view

Comment: @jack my table is users and my model is user

Comment: @AnujShrestha it doesn't have problem because when i define a variable without using $user i get data in view

Comment: I got that already, it's in your question, no need to repeat it in the comments. Also answers none of my questions.

Comment: As @kerbholz mentionned, you most likely have something that modify your $user somewhere in your code, can you try `return view('auth.verification',['user_test'=>$user]);` and `dd($user_test)` in your view? are you using `View::share('user', ...);` anywhere in your code ?

Comment: @kerbholz yes I have another view that use $user and when I do $user=User::find(1) and dd($user) it returns null

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I did return view('auth.verification',['user_test'=>$user]); and still return empty collection and no i dont user View::share

Comment: So you are saying nothing gets posted to your blade file, no matter what? Do you get redirected to a different route/view where any variables get lost? Or any middleware in place?

Comment: @kerbholz actually everything gets posted to my blade file except variables that uses $user and no i dont have any middleware on this route

Comment: Does it work when you use a different view, on a different route maybe? Can you edit your question and paste the `auth.verification` blade?

Comment: @kerbholz no it doesn't work even in different view, I paste my view in my question too

Comment: maybe you can see this [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19662)

Comment: @jack no I dont have any syntax problem

Comment: Just do `dd($user);` before `return` statement. And if you are able to access the user data using any other variable then it is surely a problem due to $user variable being overwritten by View Composer or something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    return view('auth.verification')->with('user_details',$user);
}
```

In view check it is coming or not

```
@if(isset($user_details))
   {{$user_details}}
@else
    No User Found
@nedif
```